# GCP batch Data Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm working on GCP data pipeline. I'm using Dataflow, Dataproc, and destination is big query. I have created multiple data pipelines in AWS and this is my first time in GCP.

In AWS I used deeq with Glue for data validation after landing files in the staging area; so my question is do we have any similar deeq service in GCP which I can use for data validation or DataProc,Dataflow or any other service will do it by own.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more details about how you use Deequ with Glue for data validation?